# Appcelerator Android New Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Is it possible to use the new Android bottom navigation in Appcelerator Titanium? If not, any idea when it will come out? I want to use it in combination with the ActionBar.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html

Comment: I created a simple bottom nav bar simply by creating a View in Allow and setting bottom: 0 and will have to do for now. The nice thing about using NativeScript - even though I primarily use Appcelerator because of its simplicity - is the ability to quickly use the latest widgets without waiting months, if ever, for a bridge to be created. This is what I use for NativeScript: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible and is not pending in jira.
[Android: Support Android 5.0 Functionality](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17487)

Comment: First of all Google needs to integrate this component into the Android SDK. There's 3rd party libs like [this](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) that you wrap in a module or use with hyperloop.

Comment: Any examples or additional info on how to wrap in a module or use with hyperloop?